# Tor can't start. Unknown option 'GeoIPv6File'

Tags: configuration, ipv6

Tor v0.2.3.25 (git-3fed5eb096d2d187) 
It is from Tor Browser bundle, but I need only Tor daemon.
Linux 3.11.0-26-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The error message:

```
Jul 03 01:21:04.740 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'GeoIPv6File'.  Failing.
Jul 03 01:21:04.740 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

If I comment out GeoIPv6File in torrc, tor works well, except warnings about "[warn] Unrecognized SocksPort option '"IPv6Traffic"'". 
But this option is correct and described in manual, isn't it?

Is something wrong with IPv6 configuration?

Comment: Hi, what is your question about? `GeoIPv6File` or `SOCKSPort`? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an ancient copy of Tor Browser. Download an up to date version from https://www.torproject.org/

Or install the Tor system daemon from the Debian and Ubuntu repos by following the guide at https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html

(Also that's a pretty old kernel...you should definitely be doing software updates)

Comment: It is from tor-browser-linux64-6.0.2_en-US.tar.xz bundle. And there is the same version at download page: Version 6.0.2 - Linux (64-Bit).

Comment: Oops! It is my stupid mistake. It was another tor old executable, not from bundle.